# jquery/html: Multiple links targeting single iframe generated by jquery

Tags: jquery, css, html, jquery-ui

I have a basic overlay setup using css/html/jquery and it goes like this:

```
<a class="activator" id="activator" style="" href="#">hello</a>

<div class="overlay" id="overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
<div style="display: none;" class="box" id="box">
     <a class="boxclose" id="boxclose">X</a>
      <iframe src="http://url" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;"></iframe>
</div>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://goo.gl/LKdBi"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $('#activator').click(function(){
                $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast',function(){
                    $('#box').show('fast');
                });
            });


            $('#boxclose').click(function(){
                $('#box').hide('fast',function(){
                    $('#overlay').fadeOut('fast');
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
```

This allows the link clicked, to open up a simple overlay that can be closed by clicking the X.

My question is, I'd like to have multiple links to click on that either open up their own overlay or use the same one (I'd think using the same iframe is doable). Is there a more simple method for what I'm attempting? I haven't been able to figure it out short of making separate calls for each different link I have.

edit:

Ideally, I would have 5 or so links, each of them when clicked, opens the overlay and displays the url it's pointing at. the overlay can then be closed by clicking away on the background or the 'X'.

Thanks

Comment: So are you are only wanting one overlay and one iframe and will all the links be near eachother?

Comment: If that's possible I'd like to have only one overlay/iframe, I can accomplish this with copying the code for each link but that seems a little tedious, I just thought there was a better way. 

The links are another story, they're made up of text using @font-face, and each letter is individually positioned to fit the shape of an object, and placed inside a div that's wrapped by an <a>.

Comment: I will update my code and create a jsfiddle for you.

Comment: Wow, thank you! I'm still fiddling here, will update if I can get it also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the [closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) and [next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) functions. Also, since you will have multiple links, you will need to use classes instead. Something along these lines should work for you:

```
$(function() {
    $('.activator').click(function(){
        $(this).next('.overlay').fadeIn('fast', function(){
            $(this).next('.box').show('fast');
        });
    });


    $('.boxclose').click(function(){
        $(this).closest('.box').hide('fast',function(){
            $(this).closest('.overlay').fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

Since you are only wanting one iframe and overlay. Here is a simplified version that should work for you:

**HTML**:

```
<a class="activator" href="http://www.google.com/">hello</a>
<a class="activator" href="http://www.bing.com/">hello</a>

<div class="overlay" style="display:none;"></div>
<div class="box" style="display: none;">
    <a class="boxclose">X</a>
    <iframe class="frame" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; left: 0px; bottom: 0px;> </iframe>
</div>
```

**Javascript**:

```
$(function() {
    $('.activator').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.frame').attr("src", this.href);

        $('.overlay').fadeIn('fast', function(){
            $('.box').show('fast');
        });
    });


    $('.boxclose').click(function(){
        $('.box').hide('fast',function(){
            $('.overlay').fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/XcxYP/1/)

Comment: Your `closest` methods do not select the target elements.

Comment: I was working on that just when you posted. I made some updates. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can use the classes:

```
$(function() {
      $('.activator').click(function(){
          $(this).next('.overlay').fadeIn('fast',function(){
             $(this).find('.box').show('fast');
          });
      });

      $('.boxclose').click(function(){
          $(this).parent().hide('fast',function(){
              $(this).closest('.overlay').fadeOut('fast');
          });
      });
});
```

Comment: could  you elaborate? if i use a class, how will that change the src of the iframe to the link that's being clicked?

Comment: @afrotaint Yes, the `activator` selects the next element which is the `overlay`, other things are DOM traversings that you can use the  `$(this)` for selecting the elements.

Comment: @afrotaint In your current design, you will have multiple iframes so there should be no need to change the url. Are you wanting to have only one iframe? If so can you update your question with the ideal html you would like to use?

Comment: I've updated it with the simplest explanation I can think of, sans the html just because it's some links, thanks